# Asterisk Symbol Meaning On a Particular Paper

Tags: products, article-writing

hope you are all doing well.

I am currently reading an article about quadcopters and on dynamic equations there is an asterisk symbol operation which I do not understand.

[image]

I know that it does not represent cross product (as a different notation used for it). I do not think it represents convolution either (I might be wrong). I thought that it might be representing dot product. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Would you have a link to the paper?

Comment: I have found the document: it is a MSc of Cranfield University https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.96.8228&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Generally speaking, unlike a PhD thesis, a MSc Thesis is often not self-contained, and in certain cases, not fully reliable...

Comment: In fact, the "*" sign is plainly a multiplication...

Comment: That was what I thought as well, however I just wanted be completely sure since I need to create a model from those equations. Thank you so much for your insights.

Comment: I agree with the theory that it's a normal scalar multiplication. On page 23, we see "3 * 1.07" and other uses of this symbol that clearly mean multiplication in those cases.